# Change font-family using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change the `font-family` of a string embedded inside a function of jQuery. I have tried every means without luck. Please help me. Here is the code:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".element").typed({
    strings: ["Web/Graphic Designer"],
    typeSpeed: 70,
    showCursor: false,
  });
});
```

The `font-family: 'HelveticaLTStd-Roman'` but I can't change it to my preferred font. All help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What is `typed()`? Is it a library you're using? If so, could you please add a link to it

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this. Adding .css() for adding the specific font on your selected elements.

```
$(function() {
  $(".element").typed({
    strings: ["Web/Graphic Designer"],
    typeSpeed: 70,
    showCursor: false,
  }).css("font-family", "HelveticaLTStd-Roman");
});
```

Here is jQuery's offical documentation on .css http://api.jquery.com/css/

Don't forget to include the font to your project.